# What is the best human sorting algorithm for papers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have 500 papers in random order. Every one of them has a number 1 - 3000, non repeatable. What is the fastest way for me to order them from smallest to biggest number? I know this is kind of unrelated, but it's sort of a brain program :)

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but typically people sort manually using something akin to a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As @Phylogenesis comments, something like a card sorter with 10 bins, radix sort from least to most significant digit. You have 10 "slots" numbered 0 to 9. You go through the sheets, placing all the sheets with digit "x" in the last digit face down into slot "x". You then grab the sheets from slot 9 and place them face up, then grab the sheets from slot 8 and place them face up on the sheets you grabbed from slot 9, and so on, until the sheets from slot 0 are placed face up on top of the stack of sheets. Then repeat the process for the 2nd digit from the right, then the 3rd digit from the right, and then the 4th (most significant) digit.